# Nuget Package - Web.config.transform Add

Tags: asp.net, nuget, nuspec

I'm creating a NuGet package and want it to update the web projects Web.Config file with certain settings. I am using the web.config.transform to edit the web.config file of an application. It's working well when I simply add appSettings - like so:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="WebPToolFolder" value ="~/Tools"/>
    <add key="ImagesFolder" value ="~/Content/themes/base/images"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

However, if I try an add to the staticContent it doesn't seem to alter the tags. For example, here is the web.config.transform file:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="WebPToolFolder" value ="~/Tools"/>
    <add key="ImagesFolder" value ="~/Content/themes/base/images"/>
  </appSettings>
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".webp" mimeType="image/webp" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

It updates the appSettings, but not the staticContent tags - any ideas?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem?

Comment: Nope, still no luck yet!

Answer (score 4):

Old question but if anyone lands on it the following should work:

In your case to add/update the staticContent element:

**It's an alternative solution, so you won't use the .transform file, but rather the web.config.install.xdt (and web.config.uninstall.xdt) which I find better:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <!-- some other elements -->
  <staticContent xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".webp" mimeType="image/webp" xdt:Locator="Match(fileExtension)" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" />
  </staticContent>
  <!-- some other elements -->
</configuration>
```

This way you don't need to do any pre-update preperations, just upgrade the package.

Check [this post](https://docs.nuget.org/create/configuration-file-and-source-code-transformations) for XDT support from Nuget 2.6 onwards.

Answer (score 3):

You need to put an empty `<staticContent></staticContent>` in your web.config and then use the xdt:Transform="Insert" on the element like this:

Your web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
     <add key="WebPToolFolder" value ="~/Tools"/>
     <add key="ImagesFolder" value ="~/Content/themes/base/images"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
    </staticContent>
  <system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

And then you can insert a value in your transform file like this:

```
    <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".webp" mimeType="image/webp" xdt:Transform="Insert"/>
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

Took me a while to find out. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding an xdt:Transform="Replace" attribute to the tags you want to update?

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <appSettings>
    <add key="WebPToolFolder" value ="~/Tools" xdt:Transform="Replace"/>
    <add key="ImagesFolder" value ="~/Content/themes/base/images" xdt:Transform="Replace"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".webp" mimeType="image/webp" xdt:Transform="Replace"/>
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

There's some good Microsoft documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx)

If you post the initial markup and what you want it to look like maybe we could help a bit more :)